# Bind variable implementation in i-net clear reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, report

We are using   `i-net clear 7.7 version` and `Oracle 11g`. We are writing query blocks in reports by passing prompts values in where condition.

`select DECODE(INVM.ROUND_OFF_APPLIED,'Y', (SELECT SUM(INVD1.RND_OFF_LOCALCHARGERATE)
FROM fs_fr_frtinvoicedtl    invd1
where invm.frtinvoiceid=invd1.frtinvoiceid),(SELECT sum(invd1.LOCALCHARGERATE) 
FROM fs_fr_frtinvoicedtl    invd1
where invm.frtinvoiceid=invd1.frtinvoiceid )) total_charge
from fs_fr_frtinvoicemaster invm
where invm.frtinvoiceid=  {?InvoiceID}`

But in Data Base these queries are passing as hard parsing to Data Base.

Please advise how to keep bind variables in i-net clear reports.